# Single word adjective for 'temperature-related'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

As temporal is the adjective which describes things relating to time, is there such a (non-hyphenated) word for temperature? The hyphenated 'temperature-related' works, but I'm curious about non-hyphenated ones.

For context, I'm looking for an equivalent phrase to "one's culinary preferences" but with the word as described above.

Google has thus far been unhelpful in my search, though it did lead me to this fantastic list: [Adjectives of Relation](https://phrontistery.info/genitive.html).

Comment: You claim that 'temperature-related' ... is not a single word'. It depends on the definition of _word_. [This source](http://www.absolutewrite.com/forums/showthread.php?t=145811) has: 'Is there an accepted rule in publishing about whether hyphenated words and phrases are counted as one word or multiple words?' ... 'I've seen both ways listed in submission guidelines, so I'm not sure there is one definitive answer.'

Comment: Fair point. Either way, I don't want a hyphen.

Comment: Really, Aidan? Can you explain why you can't accept a hyphen?

In any case, can you explain what your dictionaries, thesauruses or search engines left unclear?

Comment: I've edited the question to specify that I'm interested in non-hyphenated words. I really don't care whether you consider a word to be allowed to have hyphens or not; rather, I'm curious if anyone knows a word that I'm looking for. Like many things in writing, it's not that big a deal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps *thermal* would work.

> **thermal** *adjective*
>
> Relating to heat:
>   *thermal conductivity*
>   *the thermal properties of food*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thermal)

Answer (score 4):

There is **thermic** or **thermal**, "related to heat", which would fit your context. Temperature is, after all, exclusively about the presence and quantity of energy in the form of heat. A thermometer measures temperature. Greek *thermos* means "hot", Latin *temperatura* means something like "measurement, temperature", ultimately from *tempus*, "(proportion of) time".

Answer (score 0):

If you were referring to scientific measures of temperature, **[caloric](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/caloric?q=caloric)** might suit

> Of or relating to heat; calorific

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a culinary book, you could use

> "one's **heating** preferences"